# Problema Ao puxar dados de tabelas diferentes para Inputs

Tags: php, html, table

Estou com um problema na hora de puxar puxar os valores que estão dentro de duas `tables` diferentes para alguns `inputs.` Ao fazer o clicar em um `tr` da `table` o `script` criado puxar seus valores e manda para alguns `Inputs` que estão na mesma pagina, ao fazer isso com apenas uma tabela o código funciona perfeitamente.

eis o código que usei na primeira `Table`

```html
 <form action ="evento.php?reserva=true" method = "post">
      <div class="col-md-12 form-group form-group-lg">
      <center> <h2>Equipamentos
</h2></center>
</div>
 <table border="2"  id='table'>
 <thead>
<tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Equipamento</th>
  <th>Cor</th>
  <th>Marca</th>
  <th>Categoria</th>
</tr>
<style type="text/css">
  tbody tr:hover{background-color:#555} 

</style>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7"><center><script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
    dayName = new Array ("domingo", "segunda", "terça", "quarta", "quinta", "sexta", "sábado")
monName = new Array ("janeiro", "fevereiro", "março", "abril", "maio", "junho", "agosto", "outubro", "novembro", "dezembro")
now = new Date
document.write (" Hoje é " + dayName[now.getDay() ] + ", " + now.getDate () + " de " + monName [now.getMonth() ]   +  " de "  +     now.getFullYear () + "   ")
document.write ( + now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds() )
</script></center></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<center>
  <?php
            //include_once "conexao.php"; 
            $sql = "select * from equipamentos";
            $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
            if($result){
            while($linha1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tbody>
       <tr id="<?php echo $linha1['id_equipamento']; ?>">
          <td data-target="id_equipamento"> <?php echo $linha1['id_equipamento'];?></td>
           <td data-target="nomeequip1"> <?php  echo $linha1['nomeequip'];?></td>
           <td data-target="corequip1"> <?php  echo $linha1['corequip'];?></td>
           <td data-target="marcaequip1"> <?php  echo $linha1['marcaequip'];?></td>
           <td data-target="categoriaequip1"> <?php  echo $linha1['categoriaequip'];?></td>      
   </tr>
        <?php
          }//fim do while
          }//fim do if 
          ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

E o `Script`

```html
            <script type="text/javascript">
    $('tbody tr').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.each($('#'+id+" td"),function(){
            var target = $(this).data('target');
            $("input[name='"+target+"']").val($(this).html());
        });
    });
</script>
```

E são para esses `Inputs` a qual os dados da primeira `Table` são direcionados

```html
 <div class="form-group your-id">
    <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text  wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control form-control" name="id_equipamento" style="display: none">
  </div>
   
           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 form-group form-group-lg">
 Nome Do Equipamento:<br/>
  <div class="form-group your-equip">
    <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text  wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control form-control" name="nomeequip1" disabled required>
  </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 form-group form-group-lg"> Marca:<br/>
      <div class="form-group marca">
        <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required  form-control form-control" name="marcaequip1" disabled required>
      </div> 
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 form-group form-group-lg">
 Cor:<br/>
  <div class="form-group cor">
    <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text  wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control form-control" name="corequip1" disabled required>
  </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 form-group form-group-lg"> Categoria<br/>
      <div class="form-group Categoria">
        <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required  form-control form-control" name="categoriaequip1" disabled required>
      </div> 
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group form-group-lg"> Data da Reserva<br/>
      <div class="form-group Categoria">
        <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-data wpcf7-validates-as-required  form-control form-control" type="date" name="data" required>
      </div> 
      </div>
```

porem recentemente tive a necessidade de adicionar outra `Table` com dados diferentes e desejo que ela possa fazer a mesma coisa que a primeira `table`. Criei novos `inputs` e tentei direcionar os valores dessa segunda `table` para esses novos `inputs`, mas ai que me apareceu o problema que enfrento atualmente. Ao fazer o click na segunda `table` ela simplesmente puxar os dados errados para os campos errados, em vez de pegar os dados da segunda `table` e levar para os `inputs` direcionados, ela pegar os dados da primeira `Table` e simplesmente atualizam os dados que então nos primeiros `Inputs`.

Código e `Inputs` da Segunda `Table`

```html
<table border="2">
  <div class="col-md-12 form-group form-group-lg">
      <center> <h2>Professores
</h2></center>
</div>
   <thead>
    <tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Professor</th>
</tr>

</thead>
          <?php
            $sql = "select * from professor";
            $result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
            if($result){
            while($linha1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tbody>
      <tr id="<?php echo $linha1['id_professor']; ?>">
          <td data-target="id_professor"> <?php echo $linha1['id_professor'];?></td>
           <td data-target="nomepro1"> <?php  echo $linha1['nomepro'];?></td>     
       </tr>
</tbody>
<?php
          }//fim do while
          }//fim do if  
          mysql_close($con);
?>
</table> 






 <div >
    <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text  wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control form-control" name="id_professor" >
  </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group form-group-lg"> Professor<br/>
      <div >
        <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-data wpcf7-validates-as-required  form-control form-control"  name="nomepro1">
      </div> 
      </div>
```

o `Script` que uso para ambos é exatamente o mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Considere colocar ids diferentes das**

```
 <tr id="<?php echo $linha1['id_equipamento']; ?>">
```

**nas**

```
 <tr id="<?php echo $linha1['id_professor']; ?>">
```

*Exemplo para teste* com os ids 1 e 2 na primeira tabela e 3 e 4 na segunda tabela

```js
    $('tbody tr').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.each($('#'+id+" td"),function(){
            var target = $(this).data('target');
            $("input[name='"+target+"']").val($(this).html());
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action ="evento.php?reserva=true" method = "post">
      <div class="col-md-12 form-group form-group-lg">
      <center> <h2>Equipamentos
</h2></center>
</div>
 <table border="2"  id='table'>
 <thead>
<tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Equipamento</th>
  <th>Cor</th>
  <th>Marca</th>
  <th>Categoria</th>
</tr>
<style type="text/css">
  tbody tr:hover{background-color:#555} 

</style>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7"><center><script language=javascript type="text/javascript">
    dayName = new Array ("domingo", "segunda", "terça", "quarta", "quinta", "sexta", "sábado")
monName = new Array ("janeiro", "fevereiro", "março", "abril", "maio", "junho", "agosto", "outubro", "novembro", "dezembro")
now = new Date
document.write (" Hoje é " + dayName[now.getDay() ] + ", " + now.getDate () + " de " + monName [now.getMonth() ]   +  " de "  +     now.getFullYear () + "   ")
document.write ( + now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds() )
</script></center></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<center>

<tbody>
       <tr id="1">
          <td data-target="id_equipamento"> id_equipamento</td>
           <td data-target="nomeequip1">nomeequip</td>
           <td data-target="corequip1"> corequip</td>
           <td data-target="marcaequip1">marcaequip</td>
           <td data-target="categoriaequip1"> categoriaequip</td>      
   </tr>
          <tr id="2">
          <td data-target="id_equipamento"> id_equipamento2</td>
           <td data-target="nomeequip1">nomeequip2</td>
           <td data-target="corequip1"> corequip2</td>
           <td data-target="marcaequip1">marcaequip2</td>
           <td data-target="categoriaequip1"> categoriaequip2</td>      
   </tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<div class="form-group your-id">
    <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text  wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control form-control" name="id_equipamento" style="display: none">
  </div>
   
           <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 form-group form-group-lg">
 Nome Do Equipamento:<br/>
  <div class="form-group your-equip">
    <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text  wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control form-control" name="nomeequip1" disabled required>
  </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 form-group form-group-lg"> Marca:<br/>
      <div class="form-group marca">
        <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required  form-control form-control" name="marcaequip1" disabled required>
      </div> 
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 form-group form-group-lg">
 Cor:<br/>
  <div class="form-group cor">
    <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text  wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control form-control" name="corequip1" disabled required>
  </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 form-group form-group-lg"> Categoria<br/>
      <div class="form-group Categoria">
        <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required  form-control form-control" name="categoriaequip1" disabled required>
      </div> 
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group form-group-lg"> Data da Reserva<br/>
      <div class="form-group Categoria">
        <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-data wpcf7-validates-as-required  form-control form-control" type="date" name="data" required>
      </div> 
      </div>
      
      <table border="2">
  <div class="col-md-12 form-group form-group-lg">
      <center> <h2>Professores
</h2></center>
</div>
   <thead>
    <tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Professor</th>
</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>
      <tr id="3">
          <td data-target="id_professor"> id_professor1</td>
           <td data-target="nomepro1"> nomepro1</td>     
       </tr>
       <tr id="4">
          <td data-target="id_professor"> id_professor2</td>
           <td data-target="nomepro1"> nomepro2</td>     
       </tr>
</tbody>

</table> 


 <div >
    <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text  wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control form-control" name="id_professor" >
  </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 form-group form-group-lg"> Professor<br/>
      <div >
        <input class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-data wpcf7-validates-as-required  form-control form-control"  name="nomepro1">
      </div> 
      </div>
```